# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIAlert

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, uialertview

I'm using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification to scroll the view up and down when the keyboard is called. This works fine for the most part. However, the keyboard has a done button which can produce a UIAlert. Without the UIAlert there is no problem, but if the UIAlert is called something strange happens to the scrollview, it seems to stop working do to the size of it becoming smaller.

this is the code I'm using:

```
    func adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let value = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    let keyboardFrame = value.CGRectValue()
    let adjustmentHeight = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) + 70) * (show ? 1 : -1)


    scrollView.contentInset.bottom += adjustmentHeight
    //scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom += adjustmentHeight
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyboardVisible == false {
    adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(true, notification: notification)
    keyboardVisible = true
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(false, notification: notification)
    keyboardVisible = false
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

the keyboard then has a button that has the following code:

```
func displayAlert(title:String, message:String, view:UIViewController){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    }))
    view.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The result is that the alert is given, then when I press the OK button the scrollview breaks.

Can anyone help? Let me know if you need more code

Comment: Try calling your `displayAlert()` function after the keyboard has been completely dismissed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would firstly recommend you to use table view instead of scroll view if possible. Second, I don't know if you tested but these notifications get called more than once and they don't behave as you expect sometimes. I haven't tried it but I assume that once you display UIAlert one of these methods is triggered and then your content size goes crazy. Try setting breakpoints and see what goes on. Also, try dismissing keyboard on return and then call displayAlert(). Also, from experience this deinit method where you remove observers does not get called when you go from the screen, I don't know if you have a reason for using it or? It's better do use viewWillAppear, viewWillDissapear methods.

Comment: Thanks Nermin, Your answer helped me to get to the bottom of this. The answer was actually really stupid. As you pointed out the notifications arent that reliable. Sometimes they get called more than once as you pointed out. To prevent this I put a keyboardVisible bool to monitor it more efficiently. I stupidly forgot to add the 'if keyboardVisible == true{...} to the keyboardWillHide. Problem solved!